# How do I connect to a remote MySQL database in Pentaho Report Designer?

Tags: mysql, pentaho

I already installed pentaho report designer in my laptop platform ubuntu 10.10. I need to create report but the problem was how to connect the mysql database map in other server not in my laptop. I already tried researching but I cannot understand is there any step by step way on how to work on this?

Please help me badly needed this week. Thank you!!! I would appreciate any assistance you can give.

Answer (score 0):

Don't really know anything about Pentaho, but you may find the Pentaho forum a useful place.

http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?58459-how-to-connect-to-database-MySQL

This may help

http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/COM/Designing+Reports+With+MySQL+and+JNDI

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to clone the database locally to your laptop, and use JNDI definitions (which you can put in ~/.pentaho/simple-jndi/default.properties for PRD, and configure with Pentaho Administration Console for bi-server) - and as long as the JNDI sources have the same name, and point to databases with the same schema, your reports should work fine when you deploy them.

Dave.